# Windows Azure Table CompareTo Not Working

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a Windows Azure Table Called ChannelsVideos which has been denormalized to hold both the Channels and Videos together. The partitionKey is made up of the Category and Title of the Channel like so:

Business-Some Channel Title
Religion-Another Channel Title

I use the "-" character to delimit them.

I have a Kind property which is either Channel or Video to indicate whether the "row" is a channel or video entry.

The problem I am having is trying to count the number of channels for a particular user.  I have a statement that looks like this:

```
return (from g in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<ChannelVideoEntity>(Enums.Tables.ChannelsVideos.ToString())
                        where g.PartitionKey.CompareTo(categoryAndUser.CategoryID + "-") >= 0
                            && g.Kind.Equals(Enums.TableKinds.Channel.ToString())
                            && g.UserID.Equals(categoryAndUser.Key)
                        select g).AsTableServiceQuery().Execute().Count();
```

What is actually happening is that the videos for the channel are being counted as well.  Why is that?  So for example if I create a channel and add 4 videos to it then the channel count that gets returned from the above statement is 5.  Because it counts the channel and then the 4 videos associated with the channel.  All I want is the channel count which should be 1.

What am I doing or not doing can anyone see?  Am I using the compareTo incorrectly, how should I be using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some manual tests and came up with this test to manually go through all the categories via a range:

```
int c1 = (from g in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<ChannelVideoEntity>(Enums.PazoozaTables.ChannelsVideos.ToString())
      where (g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("ART AND HISTORY-") >= 0 && g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("BUSINESS-") < 0)
        && g.Kind.Equals(Enums.TableKinds.Channel.ToString())
        && g.UserID.Equals(FacebookUserID)
      select g).AsTableServiceQuery().Execute().Count();

int c2 = (from g in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<ChannelVideoEntity>(Enums.PazoozaTables.ChannelsVideos.ToString())
      where (g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("BUSINESS-") >= 0 && g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("ENTERTAINMENT-") < 0)
        && g.Kind.Equals(Enums.TableKinds.Channel.ToString())
        && g.UserID.Equals(FacebookUserID)
      select g).AsTableServiceQuery().Execute().Count();

int c3 = (from g in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<ChannelVideoEntity>(Enums.PazoozaTables.ChannelsVideos.ToString())
      where (g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("ENTERTAINMENT-") >= 0 && g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("ENVIRONMENT-") < 0)
        && g.Kind.Equals(Enums.TableKinds.Channel.ToString())
        && g.UserID.Equals(FacebookUserID)
      select g).AsTableServiceQuery().Execute().Count();

int c4 = (from g in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<ChannelVideoEntity>(Enums.PazoozaTables.ChannelsVideos.ToString())
      where (g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("ENVIRONMENT-") >= 0 && g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("HEALTH AND LIVING-") < 0)
        && g.Kind.Equals(Enums.TableKinds.Channel.ToString())
        && g.UserID.Equals(FacebookUserID)
      select g).AsTableServiceQuery().Execute().Count();

int c5 = (from g in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<ChannelVideoEntity>(Enums.PazoozaTables.ChannelsVideos.ToString())
      where (g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("HEALTH AND LIVING-") >= 0 && g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("LEARNING AND EDUCATION-") < 0)
        && g.Kind.Equals(Enums.TableKinds.Channel.ToString())
        && g.UserID.Equals(FacebookUserID)
      select g).AsTableServiceQuery().Execute().Count();

int c6 = (from g in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<ChannelVideoEntity>(Enums.PazoozaTables.ChannelsVideos.ToString())
      where (g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("LEARNING AND EDUCATION-") >= 0 && g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("NON HUMANS-") < 0)
        && g.Kind.Equals(Enums.TableKinds.Channel.ToString())
        && g.UserID.Equals(FacebookUserID)
      select g).AsTableServiceQuery().Execute().Count();

int c7 = (from g in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<ChannelVideoEntity>(Enums.PazoozaTables.ChannelsVideos.ToString())
      where (g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("NON HUMANS-") >= 0 && g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("PEOPLE AND PLACES AND EVENTS-") < 0)
        && g.Kind.Equals(Enums.TableKinds.Channel.ToString())
        && g.UserID.Equals(FacebookUserID)
      select g).AsTableServiceQuery().Execute().Count();

int c8 = (from g in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<ChannelVideoEntity>(Enums.PazoozaTables.ChannelsVideos.ToString())
      where (g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("PEOPLE AND PLACES AND EVENTS-") >= 0 && g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("POLITICS AND SCIENCE-") < 0)
        && g.Kind.Equals(Enums.TableKinds.Channel.ToString())
        && g.UserID.Equals(FacebookUserID)
      select g).AsTableServiceQuery().Execute().Count();

int c9 = (from g in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<ChannelVideoEntity>(Enums.PazoozaTables.ChannelsVideos.ToString())
      where (g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("POLITICS AND SCIENCE-") >= 0 && g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("RELIGION-") < 0)
        && g.Kind.Equals(Enums.TableKinds.Channel.ToString())
        && g.UserID.Equals(FacebookUserID)
      select g).AsTableServiceQuery().Execute().Count();

int c10 = (from g in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<ChannelVideoEntity>(Enums.PazoozaTables.ChannelsVideos.ToString())
       where (g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("RELIGION-") >= 0 && g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("SPORTS AND RECREATION-") < 0)
        && g.Kind.Equals(Enums.TableKinds.Channel.ToString())
        && g.UserID.Equals(FacebookUserID)
      select g).AsTableServiceQuery().Execute().Count();

int c11 = (from g in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<ChannelVideoEntity>(Enums.PazoozaTables.ChannelsVideos.ToString())
       where g.PartitionKey.CompareTo("SPORTS AND RECREATION-") >= 0
        && g.Kind.Equals(Enums.TableKinds.Channel.ToString())
        && g.UserID.Equals(FacebookUserID)
      select g).AsTableServiceQuery().Execute().Count();
```

It's now working!

As suspected it was how I was using the CompareTo method, seems as if it works like the traditional sql between operator, if you don't specify the ending delimiter it will just keep grabbing stuff!

Thanks for your input guys!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but I would suggest using select distinct:

return (from g in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery(Enums.Tables.ChannelsVideos.ToString())
                        where g.PartitionKey.CompareTo(categoryAndUser.CategoryID + "-") >= 0
                            && g.Kind.Equals(Enums.TableKinds.Channel.ToString())
                            && g.UserID.Equals(categoryAndUser.Key)
                        select g).AsTableServiceQuery().Execute().**Distinct**().Count();

I think if you actually look at the results, you will see 5 lines of the channel.

Comment: Hi tom thanks for your input.  Unfortunately the approach you suggest is after the fact.  What I'm trying to do is let Azure tables do all the work of just finding those records that match the query and return them.  So in other words I want the distinct part happening prior to returning the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking in the wrong direction. If I understand correctly, you have a clause filtering on the "Kind" property, which means videos should never come back (only channels). It sounds like that's not working, independent of the CompareTo clause.

If I'm right, you should be investigating why the "Kind" property isn't set correctly on the entities that are coming back.

Apologies if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that it is including categories other than just the one you think it is.  If CategoryID is a number, then your current query will return items from all of the subsequent categories as well.  You might need to make your category filter look a little like:

```
where g.PartitionKey.CompareTo(categoryAndUser.CategoryID + "-") >= 0
     g.PartitionKey.CompareTo(((categoryAndUser.CategoryID) + 1) + "-") >= 0
      && g.Kind.Equals(Enums.TableKinds.Channel.ToString())
```

Comment: Your right that was the problem.  In the end I had to specify a range I read from this blog:

http://computrengineer.blogspot.co.nz/2011/06/azure-table-storage-selecting-partial.html

that made it clear to me.